# CLI tool to let chess engines play each other

Tags: engines, computer-chess

I'm looking for a command-line tool to let two chess engines play a game or a tournament against each other. The tool should support UCI and/or the xboard protocol and it should allow to save the game as a PGN.

I could only find GUI programs for that purpose. Aren't there any commandline tools that can do that job?

Comment: This question is about command-line tools only. The possible duplicate does not mention that cutechess has a command-line interface.

Answer (score 2):

Try cutechess, a reliable software.